# erratic world origin/alignment for ARSessionConfiguration.WorldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

**[Note: this question was written against the beta version of ARKit during the iOS11/High Sierra prerelease period. Preserved for historical interest only]**

I'm seeing erratic placement and orientation for the world origin when I set the `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration.worldAlignment` to `.gravityAndHeading`.

The position of the origin is steady after the scene opens. But the axes are often rotated 180 degrees or 90 degrees around the Y axis.

Is there an additional setting I'm missing? I'm running a 2017 iPad (vanilla, not Pro) and Xcode 9 beta 2. I've tested a few compass apps on this iPad and they give me correct results, so I believe the hardware is working correctly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
    
    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    
    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // debug options
    let debugOptions: SCNDebugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints,ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
    sceneView.debugOptions = debugOptions

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

Here are some samples (in all of them I'm facing south).

Positive X and Z point west and north (incorrect, 180 degrees out of phase):

[image]

Positive X and Z point east southeast and south southwest (close to correct):

[image]

Positive X and Z point east and south (correct), but origin is displaced a couple of meters:

[image]

Positive X and Z point south and west (90 degrees out of phase):

[image]

From the [`.gravityAndHeading` documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration.worldalignment/2873776-gravityandheading)

> The y-axis matches the direction of gravity as detected by the device's motion sensing hardware; that is, the vector (0,-1,0) points downward.
>
> The x- and z-axes match the longitude and latitude directions as measured by Location Services. The vector (0,0,-1) points to true north and the vector (-1,0,0) points west. (That is, the positive x-, y-, and z-axes point east, up, and south, respectively.)

Comment: This looks like a very well written (and otherwise documented) bug report. [Have you filed one?](http://bugreport.apple.com) Also, neat clock.

Comment: Stuck on this as well. Anyone able to make any headway on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem currently. Did you ever really fix the problem?

Comment: @georg this question is 6 1/2 years old and likely pertains to a beta bug in Xcode/iOS of the time (see Andy Jazz's answer). Post a new question, add the link, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old thread, however even with ARKit 2 release and I am using iOS 12, Xcode 10.1 with iPhone 8, I am still getting inconsistent world origin.  In some cases where the blue line should be pointing to South, it is actually pointing to East or West.

I did try Sander's suggestion by using the location manager heading, but it is still not 100% guarantee I am getting the right direction to begin with.

Anyone has any other suggestion?

Comment: I think you're better off posing a brand new question (and maybe reference this one). We're long past Xcode 9 beta and you might be hitting a completely different issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting occasional random world origin, where Y axis is NOT aligned with gravity, but is at maybe a 45 degree tilt.   This is on Xcode 9.1 (beta) and iOS 11.0.3.   If I reset the session, it redetects the Y axis correctly. (I am using gravityAndHeading).

As for heading, I am in a new downtown multi-story metal/brick/stucco building.  Indoor Magnetic North detection is almost impossible.  I have tested this extensively with many different devices. (I was doing drone navigation).  The symptom was a floating north due to extremely low magnetic field.  So sometimes it worked, but could change even +-90degrees in a few seconds.

It looks like you are testing indoors, with some brick walls...

Answer (score 1):

I faced up with the same issue. 
My suggestion as a workaround to use `CLLocationManager`'s delegate method to get true north

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
```

In my experiments is shows more stable and correct results, although sometimes they are as wrong as `.gravityAndHeading` 's north.

Answer (score 1):

> **No additional settings for this app are required. Your code is OK.**

As you quoted from .gravityAndHeading documentation – longitude and latitude directions measured by `Location Services`. There is definitely a **bug** touching `Location Services` in Xcode 9 beta. I stumbled upon the same issue one year ago.

But now, when I'm using official release of Xcode 10, everything works fine. I tested it more than hundred times in different places (indoor and outdoor). A deviation from the true compass values is `+2`/`-2` degrees.

Tested on iPhone X (MQA82LL) in iOS 12 (16A366).

macOS Mojave 10.14 (18A391), Xcode 10.0 (10A255).

Also, read this useful and informative article: [Requesting Always Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization). There are many tips.

[image]